# Hide dialog in Easypermissions lib

Tags: android, android-permissions

I use easypermissions lib, here [link](https://github.com/googlesamples/easypermissions).
When I click "Deny" in screen 1, appear dialog in screen 2. I want to show screen 3 and ignore screen 2.

Help me!

[3 screens in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bK3VJ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

use [this](https://github.com/RurioLuca/PermissionManager) library, in which you get three events like permissionGranted(),permissionDenied() and permissionForeverDenied(),hopefully you will add your logic there

Comment: welcome, if answer is useful then please give me points by click of upper arrow above 0.